# How to sync app root template component with other components in app

Tags: ionic4

I am adding products to wish-list and storing that products in local Storage in
a component & in our root components I am showing the total count of wish-list
products. The problem is that when I add a new product in the wish-list it
will be stored in local storage and it will not update the total counts of
wish-list products in my root component of ionic application.

[image: This is the actual view of the core issue]

Comment: Can you provide some code? At first glance I would say that you need to use a service to manage your wish list state and share the count to each component.

Comment: Code is simple ! i am adding products to wish list and i stored that products in a session & from there i am using in our app root component.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Angular Service

What you need to do is generate a service which stores the Favorites data and then point that at it. Josh has a good introduction to this:

- [When to Use Providers / Services / Injectables in Ionic | joshmorony - Learn Ionic & Build Mobile Apps with Web Tech](https://www.joshmorony.com/when-to-use-providersservicesinjectables-in-ionic/)

Basically the high-level overview is that you generate a service which can be injected into each component / page that you want to use it with and then it can provide services to them.

For example you might make a login service so you can find out if the user is logged in from anywhere in the app, or you might want an analytics service, or it could be something more specific like maybe writing a weight conversion class that you can apply to many pages.

### Custom Events

Another alternative to this is to have the favourites button emit a custom event which the menu item can listen for to update its own stored favourites value.

This is introduced well in this article:

- [Using Events in Ionic to Pass Data & Messages Between Pages](https://alligator.io/ionic/events/)

The high-level overview is that you publish an event from one page:

```
this.events1.publish('my-message', ' Hello from page1!');
```

And then you handle that event on another page/component:

```
this.events2.subscribe('my-message', (data) =>{
  console.log(data); //  Hello from page1!
});
```

Comment: How  can web  use events in ionic?Can we use like we use events in c# etc.

Comment: The Custom Events technique I outlined above is being deprecated and removed in the upcoming Ionic 5 release. The new best practice is to RxJS and `BehaviourSubject`s to pass messages around. There are lots of videos on YouTube which explain RxJS but it does have a bit of a confusing start.